# Pick and place file from Excel

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-assembly

Further to the question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322934/centroid-of-component-for-pick-and-place-machine-using-eagle)

I want to know how the centroid point is calculated in Eagle software?

[image]
Above picture shows the coordinates of the 2-pin SMD connector @ (51.7,26.4).

But when I exported pick and place file and imported in Excel, it showed:

[image]

So basically, mid-Y coordinate shifted from **26.4** to **25.46**.

I'm about to give this to PCBA, I need to make sure it'll be placed at the right place or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the centroid is calculated from the **centers** of the outlying pads, so in the above footprint the centroid would be located in the middle left-right and vertically about where the white cross is.